# Is the meaning of linear viz a viz non-linear relationship different in statistics and mathematics?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Statistics and mathematics are two different disciplines. It makes sense for those who are applying various techniques for data-analysis if  a distinction between these terms is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all mathematics, the concept of [linearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity) is quite consistent. The only differnence I see is that a statistician would say that $Y=aX+b$ is linear, even thought is fails additivity property. A mathematician would say its *affine*.